# How to fix this error: 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am making an Android chat application. The user, if verified and logged in, surpasses through the StartActivity through the execution of the following code.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();

        //redirect if user is not null
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getCurrentUser()).isEmailVerified()) {
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Verify your email id!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

But whenever I run the app, it abruptly shuts down and shows me this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at com.smproductions.flingg.StartActivity.onStart(StartActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1425)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7825)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

HOW CAN I FIX THIS PROBLEM?

For more reference, please go through my other question where I added more code snippets which might be helpful.
[How to prevent users from logging in an android app, if they don't click on the verification link sent by Firebase authentication first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186043/how-to-prevent-users-from-logging-in-an-android-app-if-they-dont-click-on-the)

Comment: Why don't you simply use `firebaseUser` instead of `(Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getCurrentUser())` in your `if` condition ?

Comment: I tried but now I am getting this error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.isEmailVerified()' on a null object reference

Comment: also did your app crash as soon as you start or on any event ?

Comment: Yeah, it crashes as soon as it starts and shows the error.

Comment: You are getting `auth.getCurrentUser()` as `null` so you should remove this `if` condition `if (Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getCurrentUser()).isEmailVerified())` and you should be able to move in `else` block where user will be navigated to your `LoginActivity`

Comment: But then the user who is not email verified will also be able to use my app. That is why I added that code (it is also mentioned in my other question I added as a reference).

Comment: I have added an answer for your question please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to check first that the `auth.getCurrentUser()` is null or not from the comments you have said that you're getting `auth.getCurrentUser()` as null that means that there's no user signed in. You can learn more about the `getCurrentUser()` property [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users).

So here you should first check if the current user i.e. your `firebaseUser` is null or not so the code should be :-

```
//Check if the firebase user exist or not 
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    if (firebaseUser. isEmailVerified()) {
       // Your user is verified and can navigate to home activity 
   } else {
        // Your user is not verified 
    }
} else { 
    // You don't have a signed in user
}
```